# Nodejs Mail Merge

Tags: node.js, templates, mailmerge

Is there any library in nodejs using which I can create templates do a mail merge. I see many cloud services

- http://saaspose.com/
- http://www.docmosis.com/

Is this the only option or is there a simple way to do it in nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

I just released [node-livedocx](https://github.com/kingsquare/node-livedocx). This will probably help you out!

Comment: Looks like livedocx is having problems.